# Image is placed on touch event WP8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, multi-touch

I want to draw a path with images where user touch images is placed in that place and suppose user move finger images are placed in these positions.
 Normally in drawing app user draw a line on touch but I want to draw with Images Where on touch event please give me any suggestion if anyone have experience of such problem in windows phone development.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better example than the one I just posted.

Straight from the MS sight

```
TouchCollection touchCollection = TouchPanel.GetState();
foreach (TouchLocation tl in touchCollection)
{
   if ((tl.State == TouchLocationState.Pressed)
        || (tl.State == TouchLocationState.Moved))
    {

    //Here is where you add your logic to add images

    }
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff434208.aspx

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/b91cc6c8-4717-4109-bd08-937896e11840 please see it I had posted My problem here also now suggest me What I can do for that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply.I noticed nobody want to give answer for new bee in windows phone.

Comment: Please don't forget to click the check mark next to my answer and also the up arrow. I will take a look at your other issue now

Comment: Everyone is a newb in the beginning. I do this in a major software company and I feel like a newb every day. Just keep learning that's all that really matters.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14873226/capture-a-video-for-screen-activity-in-windows-phone-8 Please see my another problem still I have no solution for that.

Comment: AMR it's not working as u told me above please let me know another way if u have.